# R- arithmetic does not respect logical NOT operator and order of operations?

Tags: r, math, arithmetic-expressions

It appears that the logical NOT operator `!` has non-intuitive order of operations in arithemtic:

```
set.seed(42)
a  <-  sample(100, 3)
b  <-  sample(100, 3)
c  <-  sample(100, 3)
l  <-  (1:3) <= 2

a * !l - b * !l + c
# 0  0 29

# same expression, but with parentheses for explicit grouping order of operations
(a * !l) - (b * !l) + c
# 74 14 43
```

There must be something I do not understand about the `!` operator in relation to `*` or conversion from logical to numeric?

Comment: Check the `?Syntax` for operator precedence .  plus/minus comes before multiply/division

Comment: good idea @akrun, but i do not see anything informative about `!` operator precedence in `?Syntax`

Comment: It is there, the negation operator

Comment: I have *always* felt (and for a while, *thought*) that the negation operator should be as immediate as the negative operator, as locally as possibly. The concept of a greedy negator is just ... wrong, to me. Unfortunately, they did not consult me when they implemented it. (It is counter-intuitive to me that `(!F)+5` and `!F+5` are not the same thing ... even if an otherwise nonsensical expression.) Sigh. `</rant>`. Thanks @MrFlick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that in R, the negation operator `!` will apply to entire expression to the right of the operator until it gets to the end or encounters an expression with a lower precedence. It does not just negate the most immediate term. Recall also that 0 is treated as FALSE and any other number is TRUE. So observe

```
!0
# [1] TRUE
!5
# [1] FALSE
!5-5
# [1] TRUE
!5-3-2
# [1] TRUE
(!5)-3-2
# [1] -5
```

So you see in the case of `!5-3-2` the negation isn't happening until after the 5-3-2 is evaluated. Without the parenthesis, the negation is the very last thing that happens.

So when you write

```
a * !l - b * !l + c
```

that's the same as

```
a * !(l - (b * !(l + c)))
```

Because all the operations have to happen to the right of the negation before the negation can occur.

If you want to negate just the `l` terms, you can do

```
a * (!l) - b * (!l) + c
```

This is a function of the operator precedence in R (see the `?Syntax` help page for details). It's once of the last operators to be evaluated in the given expression.

Note that `&` and `|` have a lower precedence than `!` so when you do

```
!a | !b & !c
```

that's the same as

```
(!a) | ((!b) & (!c))
```

so this roughly would be what you expect if you just stick to logical operators. It just gets a bit odd perhaps when you combine logical and arithmetic operators.

Comment: "the negation operator ! applies to value of the entire expression to the right of the operator" is true here but might be misleading, it seems to me to imply `!` has the weakest precedence. Most relevant in practice is that `&`,  `&&`, `|` and `||` have lower precedence.

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper Good point. I updated to clarify that it will stop when it hits on operator with lower precedence.